# Error: relation tbl does not exist postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, postgraphile

I have written a SQL function in PostgreSQL that accesses data from another table. On running the function, I am getting following error

```
relation table2 does not exist postgres
```

Here is the function that I am creating

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(tbl1 table1)
RETURNS TABLE(a int, b text, c int, d text) AS $$
    SELECT a, b, c, d
    FROM table2
    WHERE id = tbl1.user_id;
$$ 
language sql stable;
```

Working in case I change table2 to myschema.table2

What do I do? I do not want to add schema into the query. I want it to take whatever schema the function is in.

Comment: Have you checked that table 2 exists?

Comment: Yes. it does. Have checked and ran to in editor

Comment: In that case I got nuthin.

Comment: Use a SET search_path before you execute the call to this function, or make it a fixed setting for each function

Answer (score 0):

imitate *38.5.3. SQL Functions on Composite Types* (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS)

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f15f42d7438b2bdaa9fa0738912c127d)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(table1)
RETURNS TABLE(a int, b text, c int, d text) AS $$
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table2 WHERE id = $1.user_id;
$$
language sql;
```

call it. `select  (func(table1.*)).* from table1;`

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem. I do not have problem accessing input parameters within the function. I have this error: relation \"table2\" does not exist"

Comment: then maybe the user/role cannot access the table.  most likely because of schema issue.

Comment: table2  refer to public. table2. public is your default search path. then table2 is not the same as myschema.table2. Yes, you can set the search_path add myschema. But it's better just use myshema.table2.

Comment: @VinitKhandelwal `SET search_path TO myschema, public;` better is full reference  `myschema.table2`. It's werid, you query  data cross table....

Comment: That worked. I set it in the properties